# Using @EnableBinding in DemoController.class result in spring aop fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream

In my application, using @EnableBinding upon DemoController.class result in my Log Aspect fail，have log records no more.
And, if remove @EnableBinding, the log aspect work.

**UspeController.class like this：**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/yeah/user")
@EnableBinding({OpenFileSystemOutput.class})
public class UspeController {

    @Autowired
    OpenFileSystemOutput openFileSystemOutput; 

    @PutMapping(value = "/applyAccount")
    public Result<?> applyAccount() throws Exception {
        UserMessage userMessage = new UserMessage(UserInfoContext.getUserId());
        openFileSystemOutput.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(userMessage).build());
        return ResultUtils.success("");
    }
}
```

**LOG Aspect like this:**

```java
@Aspect
public class LogAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(com.yeah..*) && @target(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController) ")
    public void executionService() {

    }

    @Before(value = "executionService()")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Api Interface: [{}], parameters: {}", request.getRequestURI(), JSON.toJSONString(getSerializableObject(joinPoint)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `EnableBinding` is deprecated as of 3.1.x versions of Spring Cloud Stream. If you can, please upgrade your code to use the latest functional model. See the [programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model) section from the docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's a good suggestion. And i had found the failure reason. it seems that the '@EnableBinding' and '@Aspect' are incomptible. so it result in the @Aspect not work in 'UspeController' . changing the pointcut to '@Pointcut("* execution(com.yeah.*.*(..)) ")'  and the log aspect works.  if you debug in joinPoint, you would see the UspeController bean proxy has lost the annotation '@RestController'. But i don't understand why ?